# MarshalJSON without having all objects in memory at once

Tags: go, marshalling

I want to use `json.Encoder` to encode a large stream of data without loading all of it into memory at once.

```
// I want to marshal this
t := struct {
    Foo string

    // Bar is a stream of objects 
    // I don't want it all to be in memory at the same time.
    Bar chan string 
}{
    Foo: "Hello World",
    Bar: make(chan string),
}

// long stream of data
go func() {
    for _, x := range []string{"one", "two", "three"} {
        t.Bar <- x
    }
    close(t.Bar)
}()
```

I thought maybe the json package had this functionality build in, but that's not the case.

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/3uwTdXqv3v)

```
// error: json: unsupported type: chan string
if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(&t); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I'm currently just building the json string myself.

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/570DuHHE7i)

```
w := os.Stdout
w.WriteString(`{ "Foo": "` + t.Foo + `", "Bar": [`)

for x := range t.Bar {
    _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(x)
    w.WriteString(`,`)
}

w.WriteString(`]}`)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

If the [json.Marshaler](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) was like this is would be trivial.

```
type Marshaler interface {
    MarshalJSON(io.Writer) error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `encoding/json` package doesn't have a way to do this yet. What you're doing now (manually) is the best way to do it, without modifying the built-in package.

If you were to patch `encoding/json`, you could modify the `reflectValueQuoted` function in [encoding/json/encode.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/encode.go)

You would want to focus on the Array case (Slice has a `fallthrough`):

```
// Inside switch:
case reflect.Array:
    e.WriteByte('[')
    n := v.Len()
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if i > 0 {
            e.WriteByte(',')
        }
        e.reflectValue(v.Index(i))
    }
    e.WriteByte(']')
```

I'm assuming you'd want to treat channel the same way. It would look something like this:

```
// Inside switch:
case reflect.Chan:
    e.WriteByte('[')
    i := 0
    for {
        x, ok := v.Recv()
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        if i > 0 {
            e.WriteByte(',')
        }
        e.reflectValue(x)
        i++
    }
    e.WriteByte(']')
```

I haven't done much with channels in `reflect`, so the above may need other checks.

If you do end up going this route, you could always submit a patch.

Comment: @iliacholy, let me know if you plan on doing that patch. It sounds like fun, and if you're not going to do it, I'd like to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the channel in the `MarshalJSON` method in your struct like this:

```
type S struct {
    Foo string
    Bar chan string 
}

func (s *S) MarshalJSON() (b []byte, err error) {
    b, err := json.Marshal(s.Foo)

    if err != nil { return nil, err }

    for x := range s.Bar {
        tmp, err := json.Marshal(x)

        if err != nil { return nil, err }

        b = append(b, tmp...)
    }

    return
}
```

Comment: That method loads everything into memory at once. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you then.

Comment: Since I like the pure idea of unpacking the channel within a custom marshaler implementation, the shown code does not deal with commas. So there will be one missing between Foo and the first value that comes out of Bar.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The best way to go about this is probably generating a structure and marshalling that instead of appending bytes. Feel free to suggest an edit, I have little time at the moment :(