# Encode json array to client

Tags: json, go

I have the opposite problem as this question.

[Decode large stream JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794355/decode-large-stream-json)

In that question, the user asks about *decoding* a large incoming JSON array.

But, how would I *encode* a large outgoing JSON array?

For example, I have a `http.Handler` like this.

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(resp)
for obj := range objectChannel {
    enc.Encode(obj)
}
```

However, this doesn't work because it ends up sending invalid JSON to the JavaScript client.

Do I have to manually fix the syntax? For example:

```
enc := json.NewEncoder(resp)
fmt.Fprint(resp, "[")
for obj := range objectChannel {
    enc.Encode(obj)
    fmt.Fprint(resp, ",") // and account for the last item
}
fmt.Fprint(resp, "]")
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: related to https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7872 ... no solution..

Comment: as you now use a channel, yes the solution you provided is good because it is simple and efficient.

Comment: As this is printed into an http responsewriter, dont forget to flush. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/19292461/4466350

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133950/marshaljson-without-having-all-objects-in-memory-at-once

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all the objects in memory, there is no point in encoding elements one by one, and you can do:

```
enc.Encode(lotsOfObjs)
```

If you get objects one by one, then manually adding [ and ] with commas in between is fine.

Comment: Sorry, bad coding example. Instead of ranging over an array, let's assume you're ranging over a channel that gives you 1 object at a time.

Comment: @mh-cbon yes, encoding.

Comment: @425nesp, yes as I said, manually adding [, ], and commas is just fine.